# Assessing variables outside scope of a function declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have several functions that work together to accomplish one task. Each of those functions live in their own file. In my main file, I compose these functions to accomplish my task.

Because of this, many functions need access to the same variables. My initial approach was to declare these variables in my main file with the expectation that I could call them within my functions.

However, when I run them I get reference errors inside my functions. My current alternative includes passing these variables into each function but it doesn't seem too elegant. I also considered making a class but I run into the issue of not being able to separate the functions into different files (for organizational purposes).

```
// doSomething.ts
declare outerVariable

function doSomething() {
  console.log(outerVariable)
}


// main
import doSomething from './doSomething.ts'

let outerVariable = 5
doSomething() // Reference Error: outerVariable is not defined
```

I don't think variable shadowing is an issue because I never create variables with those names in my functions.

Any idea on what's going on or a better way to structure the code?

Comment: Perhaps you can compose a new file to manage the `global` variables using export and import to access them in other files. But it's not a good practice to use global variables since it can be `mutated` by different sources. Try `pure` function to achieve your goal if it's possible and also that will be better for reusability.

Comment: The term 'pure function' is new to me but I may have to consider relying on this. Most of my issue with this program surrounds databases and networking, hence the shared resources.

I might have to handle all those calls in my main.ts and put more of the regular logic in my functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there ways to accomplish what you are trying to do? Yes, but maybe that's not the way to go.

It seems you need to rethink your program structure as a whole.

First and foremost, polluting the global namespace is never a very good idea (in any programming language probably). If you are writing code using pure functional style, then yes, passing the variables as arguments to all the functions is how it's done. You can read a little about this on wikipedia (first paragraphs should give you a nice overview): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

It also might be the case to minimize creating functions with side-effects as pointed in the comments of your question.

If the number of variables you are passing to theses functions is too large, perhaps you should consider splitting your code into smaller, more specialized functions/classes.

A single file usually contains only closely related functions or a single class.

Now, if you don't mind using objects, then you can pass to the functions one or more objects, grouping all your variables.

Also, the singleton pattern might be handy: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try es6 `export const variable = somevalue`

Comment: Are you suggesting I export the variables in my main file and import them in my individual functions?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could pass your variables into functions as arguments
Maybe it's worth considering reorganising them into a class, so they could access common class fields

It's generally good to decouple your code entities from each other, so passing them as arguments is better than declaring globals usually

Comment: I tried the class idea but that means having all functions stuck in one file. I also wouldn't say I'm adding many globals. In the main file they're still scoped within a container function